# Best practice for multi site development, staging, etc. [Special snowflake details inside]

Tags: database, multi-site, import

The story:

- Site A is running in Craft 3 as the primary site. (On a subdomain, if that matters.)
- Sites B and C are running in ExpressionEngine 2.
- I need to write new HTML/CSS for sites B & C.
- I need to import and cut/paste content from sites B & C so that **eventually, sites A, B & C are all running under the original Site A Craft install**.

Meanwhile, content will continue to be updated on Site A.

So...

If I clone Site A and develop with it, on my local PC, importing content from the other two sites, I can get all three sites running together. However, then I'm unsure how to reconcile the data from Site A with my development version.

What do folks recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, there are two methods I'd suggest;

1. Instead of reconciling the data from **Site A**, I would first setup **Site A** with **Site B + C** and add any new fields/sections you will need, then set up [project config](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/project-config.html) so that any structural changes you make locally on development will be made remotely. Put it live, then you/the client can populate the content on the live Craft install whilst you work on developing the theme locally.
2. I would look into the Feed Me plugin. On **Site A** you can set up [Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api) to expose all your content in JSON, then on you development site use Feed Me to import the content from **Site A**. This may take some setting up initially depending on the complexity of your site, but once it's done it's just a case of clicking a button to pull the latest content.

Hope that helps!